# Significant packet loss, ISP claims there's nothing wrong. What can I do?

Tags: networking, packet-loss

During the day things are usually fine, but at night anything that requires bandwidth (I have a 30mbps fiber optic connection, though I don't think it's end to end fiber) or a consistent connection (aka gaming) is completely useless. I've captured some WinMTR traces, and there's obviously some packet loss happening in multiple places, as soon as we get past my modem:

> ```
> |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
> |                                      WinMTR statistics                                   |
> |                       Host              -   %  | Sent | Recv | Best | Avrg | Wrst | Last |
> |------------------------------------------------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
> |                             192.168.1.1 -    0 |  886 |  886 |    0 |    0 |   21 |    0 |
> |                           192.168.200.1 -    0 |  886 |  886 |    0 |    0 |    3 |    0 |
> |          EV1-DSL-208-102-228-1.fuse.net -   88 |  185 |   23 |    0 | 3315 | 4530 | 4088 |
> |                            172.17.74.18 -    2 |  827 |  812 |   27 |   30 |   34 |   30 |
> |              EV-ZT-1.EVE1.core.fuse.net -    2 |  839 |  827 |   27 |   30 |   68 |   30 |
> |te0-0-2-2.nr11.b016343-1.cvg02.atlas.cogentco.com -    2 |  823 |  807 |   28 |   30 |   35 |   31 |
> |te0-0-1-1.rcr11.cvg02.atlas.cogentco.com -    4 |  791 |  767 |   28 |   31 |   36 |   31 |
> |te0-2-0-0.rcr21.ind01.atlas.cogentco.com -    3 |  819 |  802 |   30 |   33 |   37 |   34 |
> |te0-0-2-2.rcr11.sdf01.atlas.cogentco.com -    2 |  823 |  807 |   32 |   35 |   39 |   36 |
> |te0-0-2-2.rcr11.bna01.atlas.cogentco.com -    3 |  819 |  802 |   37 |   39 |   43 |   40 |
> |te0-18-0-34.ccr42.atl01.atlas.cogentco.com -    3 |  799 |  777 |   43 |   45 |   50 |   45 |
> |   be2173.ccr22.iah01.atlas.cogentco.com -    3 |  819 |  802 |   63 |   66 |   70 |   66 |
> |   be2066.ccr22.lax01.atlas.cogentco.com -    2 |  827 |  812 |  100 |  102 |  107 |  102 |
> |   be2179.ccr23.lax05.atlas.cogentco.com -    2 |  823 |  807 |   99 |  103 |  109 |  104 |
> |            att.lax05.atlas.cogentco.com -    3 |  815 |  797 |  101 |  105 |  122 |  105 |
> |                    cr1.la2ca.ip.att.net -    3 |  795 |  772 |   96 |  100 |  105 |  100 |
> |                   gar5.lsrca.ip.att.net -    3 |  799 |  777 |   96 |  115 |  402 |  110 |
> |               12-122-254-230.attens.net -    4 |  786 |  761 |   96 |  107 |  319 |   99 |
> |                            206.16.68.42 -    2 |  823 |  807 |   95 |  106 |  328 |   98 |
> |                   No response from host -  100 |  177 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
> |                   No response from host -  100 |  177 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
> |                   No response from host -  100 |  177 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
> |                   No response from host -  100 |  177 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
> |                   No response from host -  100 |  177 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
> |                   No response from host -  100 |  177 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
> |                   No response from host -  100 |  177 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
> |                   No response from host -  100 |  177 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
> |                   No response from host -  100 |  177 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
> |                   No response from host -  100 |  177 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
> |                   No response from host -  100 |  177 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
> |________________________________________________|______|______|______|______|______|______|
>    WinMTR v0.92 GPL V2 by Appnor MSP - Fully Managed Hosting & Cloud Provider
> ```
>
> As you can see, as soon as we're past my modem (192.168.200.1), I get 88% packet loss. That's not really going to work for me.

That's a trace to a Blizzard server, but I also get losses pinging Google.

What's most telling, though, is that in the above trace, the very first hop is a fuse.net address:

> EV1-DSL-208-102-228-1.fuse.net - 88 | 185 | 23

is very obviously my ISP's (fuse.net is a Cincinnati Bell domain). But they claim that the problem is not on their end, and that my connection is fine (they've run "tests"). When I call, I demand only to speak to senior level tech support (I'm routed to a "supervisor", the highest level of customer support), refusing to speak to the entry (reboot your router) level of support but that doesn't seem to yield any results.

What can I do? If they claim there's no problem and refuse to help me, what else can I do?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

First off, try to ping your local router. If you lose packets then. You'll know the issue is in between your PC and your router and nothing to do with your ISP.

If it's fine and you get all your packets, then you can move onto the next part of your network. which is between the router and your cabinet. If this is the case, there's their proof. Say 'Look I can ping my router fine from my PC [evidence], so the only logical explanation is that it's something not local to my immediate network'

Their job is to help you - I know it's frustrating, but help them help you. If you give them a logical train of thought with evidence. They can't really deny it.

Good luck.

Comment: Don't those first two hops (192.168.1.1 and 192.168.200.1, my router and my modem respectively) being clear already prove that everything is fine until the signal leaves my house?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, with MTR (or WinMTR) you shouldn't focus on the packet loss of intermediate hops too much because it's usually caused by thresholds on the ICMP traffic destined to themselves (because usually this kind of traffic require additional resources from them). If you see some amount of packet loss on an hop, followed by a 0% packet loss on the next hop you can be pretty sure that it's not a loss that will affect your traffic actually (in other words, a real loss on one specific hop will show the same or more packet loss in ALL the next hops till the destination).
Also, take a look at latency average to understand the performance, keeping an eye on the standard deviation (if it's too high the average latency makes no sense, but I'm not sure WinMTR can show it btw).

By looking at your output anyway, I see about 2% loss and a latency around 160ms to the last tracked hop, **nothing that give evidence of an unusable network** honestly.

Unfortunately your MTR doesn't show the full path, but if you have the same issue with other internet services you might track IPs that reply like 8.8.8.8 .

However, keep in mind that MTR doesn't represent the same flow you're using with your service; **in order to test this connectivity better you should set up an "iperf " test that uses the same sockets of yours, but this is something not achievable if you don't have any access to the remote network.** With MTR only, bandwidth information are missed, your traffic could be shaped/policed along the path in a different way compared to the one applied to MTR traffic, and so on.

Again, if your issues are not related to that specific service only, but to the whole Internet surfing, tests like www.speedtest.net/ could give you great insights.